# How do I type a static member of a function?

Tags: typescript

Having static member of a function is quite a common thing in javascript. Say this example:

```
function createSpy(fn){
  return function spy() {
    if(!spy.callCount) spy.callCount = 0;
    spy.callCount++;
    fn.apply(arguments);
  }
}
```

Here the functions created by `createSpy` have a static variable `callCount`. I have trouble finding out how to type these kinds of objects correctly in TypeScript, as the only examples I have seen of such a thing is the explicit support for `static` members in a TypeScript class.

Say I have an existing js library and would like to add proper typing for the resulting types in a `library.d.ts` file, what would I need in order to get the following to pass?

```
const mySpy: Spy = createSpy(myUtil);

mySpy();
console.log(mySpy.callCount === 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do in a TypeScript implementation is

```
function createSpy<A extends any[]>(fn: (...args: A) => void) {
    function spy(...args: A): void {
        spy.callCount++;
        fn(...args);
    };
    spy.callCount = 0;
    return spy;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQZQA4CeAPAIKJoAe2YAJgM6IZgEDaAugHwAUwYAXIi4A6ERhQBzOgJIBKRAF4OiAG5wYNOQG8AUIj2JQkWAkR1Cw0RKmJZA1esQ79z04SEQMAG08BhOOCgAakCAbl0XPV4LITFJGTDnAF8E-TMCdy9ffzAoBUQABhS9dCgQFCQ0sMSgA)

The vastly improved, although still somewhat lacking assignment syntax leveraged above was introduced in TypeScript 3.1 - [Properties declarations on functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions).

If you are writing a declaration file for an existing JavaScript implementation you have a few options.

A decent one aligned with your example usage is

```
type Spy<F extends (...args: any[]) => void> = F & { callCount: number };

declare function createSpy<F extends (...args: any[]) => void>(fn: F): Spy<F>;
```

Which would be consumed as

```
function myUtil() { console.log('something useful'); }

const mySpy: Spy<typeof myUtil> = createSpy(myUtil);

mySpy();
console.log(mySpy.callCount === 1);
```

but consumers should be encouraged to take advantage of type inference

```
const mySpy = createSpy(myUtil); // Spy<() => void>

mySpy();
console.log(mySpy.callCount === 1);
```

Alternately, and considering the benefits of inference, we could might opt to write it in a single declaration

```
declare function createSpy<F extends (...args: any[]) => void>(fn: F): F & {
  callCount: number
};
```